# Why is the op-amp not able to amplify this voltage? It's a straight-forward non-inverting configuration with ideal op-amps(LTSpice simulations)

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, simulation, non-inverting, ideal

So I have the following configuration (pretty straight forward right?)
[image]

But following are the waveforms of V_induced(the voltage to be amplified) and V_induced_amplified. As you can see, the voltage is attenuated instead of amplified by 100 as is expected. There is also some unwanted offset. I can't for the life of me imagine why, since I am using ideal-opamps. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what frequency is V induced?

Comment: 14.87MHz...but since I am using ideal op-amps it shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: i guess not ... but what if you just try various small DC offsets instead of AC? just to narrow it down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "ideal" opamp is built only with a VCCS and an R||C on the output, but that doesn't mean it has unlimited bandwidth. If you <kbd>R-Click</kbd> on the symbol you'll see that there are two parameters to set: `Aol` -- the open loop gain, and `GBW` -- the gain-bandwidth product. By default, `GBW = 10 MHz`, so you can guess that the gain is subtantially reduced at your working frequency.

But if all you need is just an amplification factor, you'd be better off using a VCVS source (<kbd>F2</kbd> -> `e`), or a VCCS + R (`g`), where `R` can be 1 Ω.

Comment: BTW, it's spelled `LTspice`.

Comment: Ohh this makes sense! However I changed the GBW to 100MHz and it still is not amplifying it completely. Could there be some other problem?

Comment: @needbrainscratched 1) Make sure you change both opamps.  2) GBW is the gain bandwidth product, so since your gain is 100 on the 2nd opamp you need to make sure you're covering the frequencies you need by an extra factor of 100.  Try `100g` instead of `100meg` and see what happens.

Comment: @needbrainscratched I'm curious: do you really need a repeater and an opamp plus two resistors for that 100x amplification? Wouldn't a VCVS with a gain of 100 do?

Comment: I would actually need to implement the circuit in hardware later on so I would have to look for an actual amplifier anyway. And btw, your suggestion worked! I tried an opamp with a 2GHz bandwidth and used 3 amps with a gain of 10. Probably not the best way to do things but oh well.

Comment: @needbrainscratched Well, you will need some hefty opamps with plenty of GBW. A quick check says that for a 20 MHz signal with 100x amplifier you'll need an opamp with 2 GHz GBW. Those tend to be expensive and, depending on the opamp, unstable for amplifications greater than ...well, certainly lower than 100x. Therefore some sort of compensation might be needed (if it works) -- a parallel cap across the feedback resistor -- which will lower the bandwidth. Not lastly, since you're working with tens of uV, you'll need good noise figures. I wish you good luck at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I will keep these points in mind.

Comment: @needbrainscratched You might be able to find a suitable dual or quad opamp and cascade the gain across multiple stages.  For example, with two cascaded opamps you can have each do a 10x stage such that the overall will be 100x.